# Proof of uniform convergence of converged equicontinuous sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, equicontinuity

**Question:**

$\{f_n(x)\}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and has pointwise convergence on $[a,b]$ (to $f(x)$) .

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x,y\in[a,b](|x-y|<\delta),\forall n\geqslant 1,|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$ .

Prove : $\{f_n(x)\}$ uniformly converges on $[a,b]$ .

**Standard Proof:**

1.Prove $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

2.$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leqslant |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|$ .

3.Use Heine-Borel theorem to deal with $|f_n(y)-f(y)|$ ( $\cup_{y\in[a,b]}(y-\delta_y,y+\delta_y)$ overlaps $[a,b]$ ).

**My 'Proof':**

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x,y\in[a,b](|x-y|<\delta),\forall n\geqslant 1,|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$ .

**1.Use $\delta$ to divide $[a,b]$ equally,so that $\forall x\in[a,b]$ , $x$ must be in $[y_k,y_{k+1}]$ and thus $|x-y_k|<\delta$:**

$M=[\frac{1}{\delta}]+1,y_k=a+\frac{k}{M}(b-a),k=0,1,...,M$ .

$\forall y_k,\exists N_k>0,\forall n>N_k,|f_n(y_k)-f(y_k)|<\epsilon$ .

$N=\max\limits_{0\leqslant k\leqslant M} N_k,\forall n,m>N,\forall x\in[a,b],\exists y_k(|x-y_k|<\delta)$ ,

**2.Estimate $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ :**

$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leqslant |f_n(x)-f_n(y_k)|+|f_n(y_k)-f(y_k)|+|f(y_k)-f_m(y_k)|+|f_m(y_k)-f_m(x)|<4\epsilon,$

**the first and fourth part is less than $\epsilon$ due to the equicontinuity,the second and third part is less than $\epsilon$ because we have picked $N$(which does not rely on $x$).**

**3.Take the sup(n,m is defined before $x$):**

$\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<4\epsilon$ .

Am I correct?Thanks for your checking!

---

Addition:

Is taking $N=\max\limits_{0\leqslant k\leqslant M} N_k$ legal?(for the maximum is well-defined only when $M$ is finite.)

In other words,does the estimation 'always' hold?

Comment: This would be much easier to read if, instead of exclusively writing expressions, you used some prose to guide the reader's thinking.  Read any (decent) textbook and you will not find proofs that look like this, for the reason I just gave.

Comment: Sorry for that.I've just edited it to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. Actually your answer is quite same with the standard proof. The key ideas are both that the covergence on any point $x$ can be controlled by the convergence on a nearby point $y_k.$ So the convergence on $x\in [a,b]$ can be concluded to the convergences on $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^M,$ while the latter one is easy to control.

The only difference is that you use Cauchy sequence to prove the convergence, while the standard proof proves directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I felt uncertain when introducing the $N$,for it's well-defined only when $M$ is finite.But the standard proof(using the Heine-Borel) does not have such problem-we can always define $\delta$ in finite numbers of $\delta_y$.So it's legal to introduce some variables(only rely to $\epsilon$),well-defined only in finite cases,to define $N$?

Comment: @shdvt For every (fixed) $\varepsilon>0,$ $M$ is finite. And that's enough.